# Am I missing something basic? Personality Insights

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, personality-insights

So this is the first time using any of bluemix service, and I'm getting the following error and can't find any help online relating to this. 
Am I missing something basic with set up?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Error is:

```
> Error: Could not find or load main class
> com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.personality_insights.v3.Main
```

Screen shot: [http://imgur.com/a/ArkP6](https://imgur.com/a/ArkP6)

Code:

```
package com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.personality_insights.v3;

import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.personality_insights.v3.model.Profile;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("kek");


    PersonalityInsights service = new PersonalityInsights("2016-10-19");
    service.setUsernameAndPassword(Blanked);

    // Demo content from Moby Dick by Hermann Melville (Chapter 1)
    String text = "Call me Ishmael. Some years ago-never mind how long precisely-having "
            + "little or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, "
            + "I thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. "
            + "It is a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. "
            + "Whenever I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, "
            + "drizzly November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before "
            + "coffin warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially "
            + "whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it requires a strong moral "
            + "principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into the street, and methodically "
            + "knocking people's hats off-then, I account it high time to get to sea as soon as I can. "
            + "This is my substitute for pistol and ball. With a philosophical flourish Cato throws himself "
            + "upon his sword; I quietly take to the ship. There is nothing surprising in this. "
            + "If they but knew it, almost all men in their degree, some time or other, cherish "
            + "very nearly the same feelings towards the ocean with me. There now is your insular "
            + "city of the Manhattoes, belted round by wharves as Indian isles by coral reefs-commerce surrounds "
            + "it with her surf. Right and left, the streets take you waterward.";

    ProfileOptions options = new ProfileOptions.Builder().text(text).build();
    Profile profile = service.profile(options).execute();

    System.out.println(profile);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a class path problem. Did you specify the jar with this class to be on your classpath when you run it (aka `java -cp...`)?